# How to connect my client computer to a CVS server

Tags: xcode, cvs, xcode4.3, ios5.1

I just need to know, in Xcode, how can i connect my computer to an installed CVS distant server. 
I have all credentials informations, the repository name, password, etc. I need just to get the equivalent interface that i got in Eclipse when i want to connect the Eclipse project to CVS distant server.

Thanx in advance for any helpful information.